# I am not sure with the solution of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I am having trouble with this integral. I know that the limits of the integral should be from $0$ to $v$ since we need to find the marginal $fv(v)$ and $0<u<v$ and then we put all the variables that are not $U$ in front of the integral. And from that point I don't know what to do.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, I just want to ask why is the substitution t=u/v, how do we determine that?

Answer (score 0):

You almost done.

$f_V(v)=\frac{e^{-v/2}}{2\pi}\int^v_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{u(v-u)}}du$.

The integral part is

$\int^v_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{u(v-u)}}du=\int^{v/v}_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{u}{v}(1-\frac{u}{v})}}d(\frac{u}{v})=\int^1_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}dt=\pi$.

where $t=\frac{u}{v}$. So, the final result is

$f_V(v)=\frac{e^{-v/2}}{2}$.

Comment: Write $\frac 1v\,du$, not $d(\frac uv)$, in the second integral.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin  Thanks for your comment. Is there any special reason ? Can we write $\frac{1}{v}du=d(\frac{u}{v})$ ?

Comment: No, because then you are making the substitution and the limits of the integral need to change. When you write $\int_a^b \dots dw$, then $w$ goes from $a$ to $b$. You need more words instead.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin  OK, I accept your point, and change the up limit from v to 1 earlier in the first integral. Thanks.